# Ubuntu Iptables FTP passive mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, ftp

I have a problem when trying to define iptables rules in my ubuntu server.

I reject all connections and allow some like FTP. 
The problem is that in passive mode I can connect but I cannot list folders.

I tried a lot a things I found on the net but no success.

In my iptables rules I have

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your iptables rules are very duplicated and think you are missing one iptables module.

```
modprobe ip_nat_ftp

-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi, what do you say the rules are duplicated ?

Comment: The modules are normally added. The command lsmod | grep ftp shows : nf_nat_ftp,  nf_conntrack_ftp, nf_nat, nf_nat_ftp, nf_conntrack, nf_nat_ftp, nf_nat, xt_conntrack, nf_conntrack_ftp, nf_conntrack_ipv4

Comment: I added the module by editing /etc/rc.local and adding the 2 lines : 
/sbin/modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp

Comment: because if one rule with new state is accepted doesn't new one rules in the output chain to work.

Comment: Hi sorry but I don't get it. If you want to say that RELATED,ESTABLISHED rules should come after then I also tried that